# JSp displays foreign currencies as junk

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, utf-8, currency

I am trying to display foriegn currencies in my jsp using formatnumber tag from apache fmt tag-lib, it displays junk char data. i can confirm that in controller 'the dynamic currency symbol value' being displayed correctly when I print out on console and I explicitly set response object encoding to UTF-8 and jsp page encoding and charset to UTF-8 as well. Setting the locale wont help as the transaction are in foriegn currencies and any transaction can be viewed on any part of the world.

Seems like there is a bug with formatnumber tag , but not sure about any alternatives for that. 
mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-taglibs-user/200308.mbox/%3C000001c36bc5$4ee81db0$0100a8c0@pentium3%3E
I checked this EURO and yen .

I pasted the part of code of my jsp http://pastebin.com/eZAKKeJ9. I tried printing out browser to make sure what's being pass to tag, so its junk line 545 tells and line 564 tell the formatnumber being passed with currency. 
  and handler http://pastebin.com/H21fdbZm . Checked the browser to make sure it had default changed to UTF-8. Any help is appreciated. 
edit: spam  doesnt allow me to post more than 2 links.

Comment: In the future, please don't paste external links to source code. Paste the **relevant snippets** straight in the question. No, do not paste the complete JSP file of >1400 lines. Just paste the relevant snippets which have influence on the result/problem. Most ideal would be if you created an SSCCE based on it, i.e. the smallest possible copy'n'paste'n'executabele code snippet which still reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From your code:

```
currencySymbol="${txnFormBean.originalCurrencySymbol}"
```

This problem can occur when the bean property actually returned a non-UTF-8 character. You need to fix it in the source where this character originated. Is it a Java file? Ensure that file is saved as UTF-8. Is it a properties file? Ensure that you use an unicode escape sequence. Is it a database entry? Ensure that the table uses UTF-8. Etc.

Comment: Balu, column on DB is Nvarchar2 that is converted to UTF-16.so I tried setting in my response object to utf-16 and override my jsp page with urf-16.  But my jsp includes a page that is encoded with default iso-8519-1. So it blows up with a binding exception and I tried using spring characterencoding filter based on url-mapping,but still it blows. Seems like page encoding over rides filter encoding. These currencies are used in many places so I cant even hardcode in my service layer. Any hints?